# TFS Build error: TF215097 - The following keys from the input dictionary do not map to arguments and must be removed

Tags: tfs, build-process, tfsbuild, build-process-template

I received the following error after removing several arguments from my build template and updating the corresponding build definition:

```
    TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition \Automated Deployments\AutoDeploy-Kentico-Test:
Exception Message: The values provided for the root activity's arguments did not satisfy the root activity's requirements:
'DynamicActivity': The following keys from the input dictionary do not map to arguments and must be removed: ServerDeploymentScriptLocation, DestinationBinDirectory.  Please note that argument names are case sensitive.
Parameter name: rootArgumentValues (type ArgumentException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Validation.ActivityValidationServices.ValidateRootInputs(Activity rootActivity, IDictionary`2 inputs)
   at System.Activities.Hosting.WorkflowInstance.InitializeCore(IDictionary`2 workflowArgumentValues, IList`1 workflowExecutionProperties)
   at System.Activities.Hosting.WorkflowInstance.Initialize(IDictionary`2 workflowArgumentValues, IList`1 workflowExecutionProperties)
   at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.EnsureInitialized()
   at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.Enqueue(InstanceOperation operation, Boolean push)
   at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.WaitForTurn(InstanceOperation operation, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.InternalRun(TimeSpan timeout, Boolean isUserRun)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildWorkflowInstance.Start()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildWorkflowManager.TryStartWorkflow(WorkflowRequest request, WorkflowManagerActivity activity, BuildWorkflowInstance& workflowInstance, Exception& error, Boolean& syncLockTaken)
```

Obviously TFS is angry because there are keys in the "input dictionary" that shouldn't be, and that's probably because I removed them. The problem is I have non clue where TFS is finding this values where it shouldn't find them.

How can this error be corrected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I had a similar issue when I removed arguments to my build definition but the build definition still retained the default values to the arguments. I would recommend trying:

1. Put the arguments back into the build definition
2. Edit the build definition and delete the default values of the arguments so they are blank
3. Remove the arguments again.

You could also try searching the xaml of the build template for the following values:

- ServerDeploymentScriptLocation
- DestinationBinDirectory

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I managed to fix the build by adding back in the variables. I haven't tried deleting them again yet, I'm a bit afraid to do so. TFS thus far has taught me a valuable lesson: Don't try to learn this tool. Nothing in this process has been smooth. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same problem when removing arguments from the build process template. Existing build definitions using the updated template reported the same error but after updating the definition the problem went away. I simply edited a value and then changed it back and saved the definition.

Answer (score 0):

One or more of the parameters have been removed from the build template XAML file, in this case ServerDeploymentScriptLocation and DestinationBinDirectory.

However, the parameter and its value still exist in TFS's build definition database.

To fix this, the build template definition needs to be refreshed and saved. In the process tab, there is a Refresh button that will reload and refresh the build definition, after which it can be saved.

To do this:

1. In Team Explore, select Builds.
2. Under "All Build Definitions", select the build to fix, right-click, "Edit Build Definition"
3. In the left pane, select "Process".
4. In the right pane, there's a bordered area labelled "Build process template", in the right of which is a "Show details" option. Expand the section by pressing the down arrow.

[image: Refreshing the Build Process Template]

5. Press the Refresh button. (In my case, I was really pedantic, and selected another build definition, saved it, then re-selected the original definition, and re-saved).
6. Initiate another build.

Source: http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2010/04/21/getting-tf215097-error-after-modifying-a-build-process-template-in.aspx